# Android NDK passing parameters to native methods

Tags: android, opencv, android-ndk

I am studying OpenCV4Android SDK, in the 2.4.5 version, with the NDK framework, using which I can use native code (written in C/C++) in the Android environment. But I don't exactly understand how parameters are passed from Android to C.

For example, in the 'mixedprocessing' sample, in the directory 'jni' there's a .cpp file named 'jni_part', whose code is:

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/features2d/features2d.hpp>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

extern "C" {

  JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_org_opencv_samples_tutorial2_Tutorial2Activity_FindFeatures(JNIEnv*, jobject, jlong addrGray, jlong addrRgba);

  JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_org_opencv_samples_tutorial2_Tutorial2Activity_FindFeatures(JNIEnv*, jobject, jlong addrGray, jlong addrRgba) {
    Mat& mGr  = *(Mat*)addrGray;
    Mat& mRgb = *(Mat*)addrRgba;
    vector<KeyPoint> v;

    FastFeatureDetector detector(50);
    detector.detect(mGr, v);
    for( unsigned int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++ ) {
      const KeyPoint& kp = v[i];
      circle(mRgb, Point(kp.pt.x, kp.pt.y), 10, Scalar(255,0,0,255));
    }
  }

}
```

In the MainActivity there's the method:

```
 public native void FindFeatures(long matAddrGr, long matAddrRgba);
```

So it's passed as parameter the native address of a Mat object, but how does it become a matrix in C?
And which features are detected from a FastFeatureDetector object?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`FindFeatures`, in Java, calls its exact equivalent in C/C++:

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_org_opencv_samples_tutorial2_Tutorial2Activity_FindFeatures(JNIEnv*, jobject, jlong addrGray, jlong addrRgba){
Mat& mGr  = *(Mat*)addrGray;
Mat& mRgb = *(Mat*)addrRgba;
...
```

This is where it becomes a `cv::Mat`. `(Mat*)` casts what is pointed by address `addrGray` (respectively `addrRgba`) to a "pointer to a `cv::Mat`". Then, the value pointed by this newly created pointer is put in `mGr` (respectively `mRgb`), which is a `cv::Mat`.

In other words, you only give to C/C++ an address in the memory, and you have to make sure that what's there actually is a valid `cv::Mat`.

---

About your second question, the FAST detector detects points of interest in the image (i.e. points that contain a lot of information). The idea is to be able to identify those points on multiple different images. To simplify, you can consider a *feature* detected by FAST as a corner in the image.